# two inputs with different importance

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN model with two inputs, like this:

```py
input_a = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[128, 128, 3])
input_b = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[28, 28, 3])

conv_a = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, 2)(input_a)
conv_b = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, 2)(input_b)

dense_a = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(conv_a)
dense_b = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(conv_b)

combined = tf.keras.layers.Add()([dense_a, dense_b])

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_a, input_b], outputs=conbined)
```

I found this network learned more informations from `input_b` branch, but my design is `input_a` is more important and `input_b` assist `input_a`. So, **I want to set different importances to those two layers, because I want to make `input_a` more important**. I implement a weighted layer:

```py
class WeightedAdd(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, weight):
        self.weight = weight
        super(WeightedAdd, self).__init__()

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        return self.weight * inputs[0] + (1. - self.weight) * inputs[1]

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0]
```

Now, I replace my Add by WeightedAdd:

<s>combined = tf.keras.layers.Add()([dense_a, dense_b])</s>
**combined = WeightedAdd(0.8)([dense_a, dense_b])**

But, it seems not work. How can I implement my idea？

Answer (score 0):

Fine! It seems works~~. Set the weight of `input_a` more bigger than `input_b` like `0.9999`, the difference after update of `input_a` is bigger than `input_b`. **But I'm not sure it whether or not works for my idea.**